# How to do inheritance in fluent NH without discriminator type column

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 classes:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual int Id  { get; set; }
    public virtual string BaseProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual string ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map each of them to its own table (fluent NH). How to do it with no discriminator type column added to [MyBaseClass] table? So I expect [MyBaseClass] table consists of BaseProperty and Id columns only, MyClass consists of Id, BaseProperty and ChildProperty columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put `IgnoreBase` to on `MyBaseClass`. It will say for FNH to map those classes independently

Comment: It would work in case I do not really need MyBaseClass being mapped. But the thing is I actually do. It is to be mapped to MyBaseClass table and used in my application as regular domain data class.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this (http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Components):

> ```
> public class Parent
> {
>   public int Id { get; set; }
>   public string Name { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Child : Parent
> {
>   public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> If you wanted to map this as a
>   table-per-subclass, you'd do it like
>   this:
>
> ```
> public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
> {
>   public ParentMap()
>   {
>     Id(x => x.Id);
>     Map(x => x.Name);
>   }
> }
>
> public class ChildMap : SubclassMap<Child>
> {
>   public ChildMap()
>   {
>     Map(x => x.AnotherProperty);
>   }
> }
> ```

So looks like this approach does not require any Db changes like adding special fields to my tables. The only problem is I do not know how to do the same in AutoMapping with Override statements. We do mapping this way:

```
public class AutoMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool IsDiscriminated(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type.In(typeof(MyBaseClass),typeof(MyClass),...)
    }
...
}

FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoPersistenceModel Instance =
            AutoMap.AssemblyOf<MyBaseClass>(new AutoMappingConfiguration())             
    .Override<MyBaseClass>(m =>
{
        ...
    }
}
```

So I'm not sure how to apply SubClass instruction in my case. Any advise?

Thanks.

Comment: I've done it this way, but looks like it needs MyBaseClass_id column being created for MyClass table that does not fit my needs, I can not change Db schema